# How to fix the issue as driver.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) is not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am able to enter the location, but once I am done with sending the location, then it should automatically click the 1st item from suggestion, but it is not working. Any work around on this?

I have tried almost all the things like inducing some wait time in order to load the suggestion and then press enter but nothing has helped me. I am newbie in selenium and python.

```
url = 'https://www.stek-usa.com/locator'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
loc = driver.find_element_by_id('storelocator-search_address')
loc.send_keys('Arkansas, USA')
loc.click()
loc.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Once enter is pressed, it should show the correct location. But that is not happening. Please help me on this.

Comment: I suppose you're trying to select an autocomplete element that is populated after you type some keys. In that case, you will need to find the returned element and then click it, because on your code you are clicking the same input in which you type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, instead of the last three lines of your code, add this:

```
loc.send_keys('Arkansas, USA' + Keys.DOWN + Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: If the autocomplete function runs a http request he will need to wait for the element to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
driver.sendKeys(Keys.chord("your location", Keys.ENTER));

This step will perform entering your location into text box and will click on first matching option, which will fulfill your criteria